# Nested Function in Swift return type casting error

Tags: casting, swift

Original Code:

```
func makeIncrement()->(Int->Int){
    func addOne(Number:Int)->Int{
        return 1 + Number
    }

    return addOne
}
```

**Question One:** does the (Int->Int) interrupted like this -- first Int    is the return type of inner function, second Int is return type of    the outer? I did little experiment myself by changing code to:

```
func makeIncrement()->(Int->String){
    func addOne(Number:Int)->Int{
        return 1 + Number
    }

    return String(addOne)
}
```

**error pop up says NSString is not a subtype of Int->String**

I tried other way around (reverse return type, but gave me similar errors)

**Question Two**: How does this type of casting work in this case ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`addOne` is a function. You cannot simply take a function and convert it into a text (`String`).

```
func makeIncrement() -> (Int -> String) {
```

Says that you want to return a function that takes an `Int` as a parameter and returns a `String`

You must create such a function first:

```
func addOneAsString(number: Int) -> String {
    return String(1 + number)
}
```

And then return it:

```
func makeIncrement() -> (Int -> String){
    func addOneAsString(number: Int) -> String {
        return String(1 + number)
    }

    return addOneAsString
}
```

See [Swift Reference - Functions](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Functions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH10-XID_204)

Comment: `-> String` means that `String` is returned. `Int` is the parameter.

Answer (score 3):

> Question One: does the (Int->Int) interrupted like this -- first Int is the return type of inner function, second Int is return type of the outer?

No, `(Int -> Int)` is the return type of the outer function, which means it returns a function that takes an `Int` as a parameter and returns an `Int`. Thus, you need to return a function that has those characteristics.